# html: &copy; doesn't show

Tags: html

when i wrote `&copy;` in my page it doesn't show the copyright symbol,

and show the point instead, just **.** it shows. maybe you know why? thanks

Comment: Could you post a bit more context?

Comment: What's the doctype? Which browser(s) did you try? Which font are you using?

Comment: Such as: inside what tag did you use `&copy;`?  What browser are you using?  Do other entities (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) work properly?

Comment: in Mozilla and IE i've  tested. other entities works fine

Comment: Helvetica is probably not an option if you're using Windows though (you might wan to try Arial instead. Be sure to have a fallback to another font (that has Copyright symbol ofcourse).
ex. font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put the copyright symbol in a `<span>` tag and in your css use a font that works.

```css
    .copyright {
        font-family: Arial,
             "Helvetica Neue",
             Helvetica,
             sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
    <span class="copyright">&copy;</span>2007 Syom Industries
```

Comment: `font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;`

Comment: @Mark Yeah, normally I'd put Helvetica first too, in fact I'd put "Helvetica Neue" first, but in this case it's just a `&copy;` symbol ;-)

Comment: @ghoppe What if i need to print `&copy;` instead of `©` symbol in HTML...Is it possible?

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser You can use the HTML escape sequence for an ampersand, therefore `&amp;copy;` will display `&copy;`

Comment: Great answer, upvoted, thanks for posting, just added a sandbox demo, too.

Answer (score 12):

Most likely — because the font you are using has a broken copyright character in it.

Without a test case it is hard to make a guess beyond that.

Comment: @David Dorward yes, you're true. but what can i do in this case? if i remoove the font, works fine, but i need that font:)

Comment: Be aware that many people may not have the font you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a `&nbsp;` before the `&copy;` works for me as well, even with the `Helvetica Neue` font.

Answer (score 0):

with me i can just put do `&copy;` with nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
<meta charter="utf-8">
```

In The heading tag and you could also add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```